# Cannot import name when running Scrapy project

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

My project name is NOTHS.

The following scripts are the `spider.py` and `items.py` that I used.

`spider.py`:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from NOTHS.items import NOTHS
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "main"
    allowed_domains = ["notonthehighstreet.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.notonthehighstreet.com"]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//a[@class='title']")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = NOTHS()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

`items.py`:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class CraigslistSampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
```

When I run this the following error occurs :

```
C:\Users\ACER\Documents\works\source code\NOTHS>scrapy crawl main
:0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity
module: 'No module named service_identity'.  Please install it from <https://pyp
i.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are sa
tisfied.  Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to s
upport it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification
.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('scrapy==0.24.4', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\commands\cr
awl.py", line 57, in run
    crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py"
, line 87, in create_crawler
    self.crawlers[name] = Crawler(self.settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py"
, line 25, in __init__
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spidermanag
er.py", line 35, in from_crawler
    sm = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spidermanag
er.py", line 31, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spidermanag
er.py", line 22, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\misc.
py", line 68, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Documents\works\source code\NOTHS\NOTHS\spiders\main.py",
line 3, in <module>
    from NOTHS.items import NOTHS
ImportError: cannot import name NOTHS
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Are the dependencies installed?

Comment: Looks like you might have the `import` line wrong. Look on line 3 of the file `NOTHS\spiders\main.py`. If that was going to work, you'd need something within `NOTHS\items.py` called `NOTHS`.

Comment: I had installed all the dependencies that were mentioned in the installation guide from [scrapy-site](doc.scrapy.org)

Comment: Thanks @LondonRob I got this now.
But the Output is not correct I will post that as next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file `spider.py`, change

```
from NOTHS.items import NOTHS
```

to

```
from NOTHS.items import CraigslistSampleItem
```